# Bad Request 400 Google Plus Login

Tags: android, android-studio, http-post, google-plus

I am typing to integrate google plus login in my application.The problem is, post method returns `Bad Request 400` status when i try to push the user credentials to server after successfully fetching them.What might be the cause of it! Any kind of help would be appreciated!!

I have copy pasted the code below:

```
public class GooglePlusLoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = GooglePlusLoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;

    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 3434;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    // private SocialLoginService mSocialLoginService;
    private String mAccountName;
    private String mToken;
    private String fullName = null;
    private String email = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && GoogleApiClient.isConnected())  {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        Plus.PlusOptions options = Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, LoginFragment.gso)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .addApi(Plus.API, options)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();


        // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
        // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
        mShouldResolve = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        signIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
                // error dialog.
                dismissDialog();
                Util.warningDialog(mContext, "Error occured during Google login. Try again");
                GooglePlusLoginActivity.this.finish();

            }
        } else {
            //show signout
            GooglePlusLoginActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + " intent data=" + data);
        Log.d(TAG, "intent data1="+data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.
            new GetAccessTokenTask(data).execute();
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }
            mIsResolving = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the device, that the selected
        // account has granted any requested permissions to our app and that we were able to
        // establish a service connection to Google Play services.

        Log.v(TAG, "google i am connected....");
        mShouldResolve = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        exitCurrentActivity();
    }

    class GetAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private Intent mData;
        public GetAccessTokenTask(Intent data) {
            this.mData = data ;
            Log.d(TAG, "intent data="+mData);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog("Fetching profile ...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            super.onPostExecute(token);
            dismissDialog();
            checkForTokenEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mAccountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            Log.v(TAG,"account name="+mAccountName);
            final String SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read";
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(mData);
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            if(acct!= null)
                Log.v(TAG," result success"+acct.getEmail());
            if (result.isSuccess() && acct != null) {
                fullName = acct.getDisplayName();
                email = acct.getEmail();
                Log.v(TAG, acct.getDisplayName());
                try {
                    mToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, mAccountName, "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
                } catch (IOException | GoogleAuthException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient, acct != null ? acct.getId() : null)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                            Person person = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
                            String photoUrl = person.getImage().getUrl();
                            photoUrl = photoUrl.substring(0, photoUrl.length() - 2) + 200;
                            Prefs.putString(Constants.PREFS_GOOGLE_PROFILE_IMAGE, photoUrl);
                            Log.d(TAG, "photo url:" + photoUrl);

                        }
                    });
             //then send to server

            Log.v(TAG,"token="+mToken);
            return mToken;

        }


        /**
         * check for token empty
         */
        private void checkForTokenEmpty() {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mToken))
                fetchGoogleProfile(); //if not empty fetch profile detail
            else{
                Log.v(TAG," token empty");
                exitCurrentActivity();

            }
        }
    }

    private void exitCurrentActivity() {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new SocialLoginEvent(false));
        GooglePlusLoginActivity.this.finish();
    }

    /**
     * fetch google profile details
     */


    private void showDialog(String message) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgressDialog.showProgress();
        if (message.isEmpty())
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        else
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(message);
    }

    private void dismissDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null)
            mProgressDialog.dismissDialog();
    }

    private void fetchGoogleProfile() {
        Log.v(TAG,"sending google plus profile to server");
        SocialLogin socialLogin = new SocialLogin(email, fullName, fullName, SocialLoginType.GOOGLE, mToken);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new SocialLoginEvent(true, socialLogin));
        GooglePlusLoginActivity.this.finish();

    }

    private void signIn() {
        showDialog("please wait....");
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}
```

This class shows `bad request 400` when posting credentials to server.

```
public class SocialLoginService {

    private static final String TAG = SocialLoginService.class.getSimpleName();
    public SocialLoginHttpListener mSocialLoginHttpListener;
    private SocialLoginType mSocialLoginType;

    public void postSocialToken(SocialLogin socialLogin) {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("UserName", socialLogin.getUserName());
        params.put("Email", socialLogin.getEmail());
        params.put("FullName", socialLogin.getFullName());
        params.put("Platform", "Android");

        String providerType = "Google";
        mSocialLoginType = SocialLoginType.GOOGLE;
        if (socialLogin.getSocialLoginType() == SocialLoginType.FACEBOOK) {
            providerType = "Facebook";
            mSocialLoginType = SocialLoginType.FACEBOOK;
        }
        params.put("Provider", providerType);

        params.put("ExternalAccessToken", socialLogin.getToken());
        Log.v(TAG, "social login post data: " + params.toString()); //This tags showing correct information.

        RestClient.post(" valid url here", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                try {
                    String response = new String(responseBody);
                    Log.v(TAG, "social login success: " + response);
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    String accessToken = object.getString("access_token");
                    String token_type = object.getString("token_type");
                    double expireTime = object.getDouble("expires_in");
                    if (!accessToken.isEmpty()) {
                        Util.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                        Util.setTokenType(token_type);
                        Util.setTokenExpireDate(expireTime);
                        Util.setLoginStatus(true);
                    }
                    mSocialLoginHttpListener.setSocialLoginStatus(true, mSocialLoginType);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mSocialLoginHttpListener.setSocialLoginStatus(false, mSocialLoginType);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.v(TAG, "social login failure: " + error.getMessage() + " " + statusCode);
                error.printStackTrace();
                error.getCause();
                mSocialLoginHttpListener.setSocialLoginStatus(false, mSocialLoginType);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the log cat:

```
02-21 15:51:11.227 1111-1111/com.app.food V/AsyncHttpClient: Beware! Using the fix is insecure, as it doesn't verify SSL certificates.
02-21 15:51:17.106 1111-2690/com.app.food V/AsyncHttpClient: Headers were overwritten! (Content-Type | application/x-www-form-urlencoded) overwrites (Content-Type | application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8)
02-21 15:51:17.439 1111-1111/com.app.food V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 55 from 55 (100%)
02-21 15:51:17.439 1111-1111/com.app.food V/SocialLoginService: social login failure: Bad Request 400
02-21 15:51:17.439 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err: cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:446)
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:160)
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-21 15:51:17.447 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-21 15:51:17.448 1111-1111/com.app.food W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-21 16:05:49.482 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.483 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.485 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.488 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.506 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.508 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.509 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.512 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.512 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.513 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.514 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.514 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:05:49.515 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.560 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.562 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.563 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.565 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.574 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.575 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.576 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.577 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.578 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.580 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.581 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.582 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-21 16:08:47.582 1111-1111/com.app.food W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

I have used the same `SocialLoginService` class for doing the same kinda work for facebook i.e fetching user credentials and posting it into server and its working perfectly.No idea why its showing that error in case of google plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem!I forgot to update the old `client Id` used in the server with the new one when I registered the project with different finger print in the google developers console. Hence the server was throwing out `bad request 400` whenever I attempted to make upload user credentials fetched from the google plus .